# RegExp: Do not split if previous character is in capitals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am currently using the following regular expression to split a text:

```
  var separators = ['!', '.', ':', ';', '?'];
  var tokens = text.match(new RegExp("[^" + separators.join('') + "]+[" + separators.join('') + "]*", "g"));
```

I now want to NOT split after a `.` whenever the character before the dot is in capitals (so: split if it's `one.` do not split if it's `onE.`. Could anyone give me a hint how I could do something like this and integrate it into my current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Premise**

Your current RegExp pattern is (ignore the added white space):
`[^!.:;?]+ [!.:;?]*`

Given an input sample of, say: `the.quick;browN.fox.jumps`
you end up with tokens:

1. `the.`
2. `quick;`
3. `browN.`
4. `fox.`
5. `jumps`

and your goal is to end up with tokens 3 and 4 bound together: `browN.fox.`

1. `the.`
2. `quick;`
3. `browN.fox.`
4. `jumps`

The rule is that if the separator is dot (`.`) and right before it you have an upper case letter (in this particular case the letter `N`) you want the dot to lose its role as separator and "bind to the rest of the text".

Furthermore, this rule only applies to dot (`.`) and not the entire set of separators you listed (`!.:;?`).

**Solution**

If what I understand is correct then your answer is (ignore the white space again):

`( [A-Z]\. | [^!.:;?] )+ [!.:;?]*`

What happened here is that instead of having just "any character except a separator" at least once in the left hand side, we simply add an alternative which is comprised of any upper case letter (`[A-Z]`) followed by a dot (`.`) which I had to escape.

Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/25UQbq/1

**EDIT**

This is how you could use this RegExp pattern in javascript:

```
var input = "the.quick;browN.fox.jumps";
var pattern = "([A-Z]\.|[^!.:;?])+[!.:;?]*";
var options = "g"; // quite important
var regexp = new RegExp(pattern, options);

var output = input.match(regexp);
// output should be ["the.", "quick;", "browN.fox.", "jumps"]
```

Comment: Thanks a great deal. This is perfect!

Comment: @GeorgeWelder Check my latest edit for a sample code in javascript

Comment: @GeorgeWelder You didn't confirm that your new rule only involves dot (`.`) and no other separators. Should it be not the case you can always turn `[A-Z]\.` into `[A-Z][.]` (we just made the dot the single member of a set) and then you can grow and shrink that set to whatever you like, for instance: `[A-Z][.;!]` etc

Answer (score 0):

one idea: loop through the string and replace every `.` that's NOT after a capital letter with a different separator, say `!`.  Then remove `.` from your list of separators, and split as you did before.